# How to reliably use UDP c++ winsock multiplayer?

Tags: c++, udp, winsock, multiplayer

I've made a winsock game server, and hosted it on a cheap VPS, but when friends connect the UDP gets blocked.

Currently I'm using port 54001 for UDP and 54000 for TCP.

**Are there any specific ports I should be using for UDP?
How are fast paced multiplayer games reliably using UDP?**

Comment: Reliably and UDP means that you need to add a layer (that the one built into TCP) to make sure the packets are processed in the correct order and that no packet is missing and that no duplicates are processed. The ports usually don't matter as long as you stay away from the first 1024 ports. You can even use the same port for UDP and TCP.

Comment: Hmm, I do have measures in order in the event of "stale" UDP packets. I was able to connect to the VPS just fine... But the friends couldnt (for UDP anyway)... I'll try the same ports!

Comment: Have you opened the ports in your firewall to let your friend's connection attemps through?

Comment: Well the server is on the VPS. It's a cheap windows server, that I just fire up using remote access, but it's not hosted on my wifi or anything. If my home PC can connect, but a friend's cannot... I'm not sure what that's suggesting--I just assumed firewall settings.

Comment: Your friend must also have opened his/her firewall for outgoing traffic for the app in question.

Comment: I'll have him try that. How would this be done for real players, without having them manually allow outgoing traffic?

Comment: Usually Windows asks if the user wants to allow the application to make such connections. You can also let the application request opening the firewall for it so that the user has to approve it. If I remember correctly there are some WinAPI functions for making such changes in the firewall.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I will try some things!